# Java- Reading input and output on JOptionPane

Tags: java, joptionpane

I'm struggling on my code, it works good with the code that I commented but it doesn't work when I use JOptionPane.showOptionDialog , I am using Option dialog its because I want that code to display a skip or cancel button and I don't know how do I change the String of that button yet too, I would be really appreciate if someone can solve this problem for me.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Login {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String userName;

        //This will ask user to input the username
        userName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter your name", "Welcome", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog   <<<This code replace the below one then it will work perfectly
        JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Welcome " + userName + "\n\nWould you like to have a tutorial about this game?", "Welcome", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog` requires more arguments than you provided. If you check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showOptionDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-int-javax.swing.Icon-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-) you'll see you have to also provide the messageType, an icon, the options and the default option, where the last 3 can be null, so your call has to be

```
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(
    null,
    "Welcome " + userName + "\n\nWould you like to have a tutorial about this game?",
    "Welcome",
    JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
    null,
    null,
    null
);
```

Comment: You saved my life thanks so much, I will take a look of the document throughly thanks!